# How to assign return value of inner class to outer variable

Tags: java, retrofit2, anonymous-class

I am beginner in Java and i am stuck with assigning return value of a variable from an anonymous inner class.

I wanted to capture List of strings which are returned from a API Call.

```
List<String> **strTopics**=null;
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

Call<List<String>> call=retrofit.getSubjects();

call.enqueue(new Callback<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<String>> call, Response<List<String>> response) {
                Log.d("prepareListData","I am success");
                strTopics=response.body();
                for(String str:strTopics)
                 Log.d("Subject Name ",str)
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<String>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("prepareListData","I am failure");
            }
        });
       //I am having challenges here. After this statement, again "**strTopics**" is becoming null.
      for(String str:strTopics)
                     Log.d("After inner method",str)
```

I just wanted to mention, if i comment the above for loop, then only i am able to print the subject names which are inside the inner class method.

If it is uncomment, then none of the for loops are invoked and nothing is getting printed. Getting **NullPointerException** in 2nd for loop. Not sure it is problem of Retrofit2 also.

Can someone help me how to overcome this problem. Whatever returned from inner class, i want those values to be used outside of it.

Please help.

Comment: That code should work in setting strTopics to another value, is it possible that the response you are receiving is null? (so it's assigning strTopics to null)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the results outside the call, you will have to wait that the call has been done. In retrofit, call.enqueue is an asynchronous task, which means that it is executed on a different thread, and it might take some time to get the result.

Here, your second loop, outside the enqueue, is actually executed before the call is finished. That's why it's still null when you are trying to access it.

To resume, it is actually executed in this order:

- first you create your call with `Call<List<String>> call=retrofit.getSubjects();`
- then you add a callback to it. This launches a background task that will get the desired informations
- while the background task executes, the main thread will move to the next instruction, which is your second for loop
- at some point, the background task finishes, and will call either the onResponse or onFailure method that you declared in the callback
- then the code inside the corresponding method is executed

It might be possible on some occasion that the background task finishes before the next instruction is started on the main thread, but you can never be sure so I wouldn't count on it.

If you need to use the result from your call somewhere else in your code, I suggest you create a method that takes the result as parameter, and call this method in the onResponse of your code.

```
void doSomethingWithResult(List<String> result) {
    // do whatever you need with that result
}

// then in your call
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<String>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<String>> call, Response<List<String>> response) {
          Log.d("prepareListData","I am success");
          strTopics=response.body();
          for(String str:strTopics)
              Log.d("Subject Name ",str)
          doSomethingWithResult(response.body());
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<List<String>> call, Throwable t) {
          Log.d("prepareListData","I am failure");
      }
});
```